# How to rewrite homepage based on hostname

Tags: next.js

I'd like to show two different pages at '/' depending on the hostname (the value for `req.hostname`). This is because I have a subdomain xxx.mydomain.com that needs to show just one page at the root URL. The idea is to have a CNAME for the subdomain that points to the same server as www. I'm using next version 11.1.2 .

My homepage (/pages/index.js) uses getStaticProps to get data for the page with a `revalidate` interval of 2 seconds. The page on the production branch works great currently without any rewriting.

I tried using the rewrites option in next.config.js and was able to use this to rewrite all other routes, but rewriting with `source: '/'` did not do anything. If the source was any other page it worked perfectly. This is pretty much what the next.config.js file looked liken when I tried the rewrite:

```
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@cal-frontends/shared']);
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' });

module.exports = withTM(withFonts({
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',  // this one still showed the homepage at '/'
        destination: '/mission',
      },
      {
        source: '/foo', // this one showed the contact page at '/foo'
        destination: '/contact',
      },
    ]
  },
  webpack(config, options) {
    return config;
  },
}));
```

I tried many strategies, including this kind of configuration in server.js

```
server.get('/',function(req,res){
  console.log('trying to redirect', )
  console.log('req.hostname', req.hostname)
  if (req.hostname === 'mission.mydomain.com') {
    console.log('this should show mission', )
    return app.render(req, res, '/mission', {})
  } else {
    handle(req, res);
  }
});
```

This unfortunately did not seem to override the static caching that happens with getStaticProps – you will only see the correct page for the hostname if you load and then reload after it revalidates.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: _"rewriting with source: '/' did not do anything"_ - Can you clarify this part? What exactly did you try in the `next.config.js`?

Comment: I updated it just now to include what I wrote in `next.config.js`

Comment: By the way, I was able to get around this by using getServerSideProps on pages/index.js , and then using ctx.req.hostname to change the render and API call depending on if the hostname included the subdomain. But I still feel that this kind of redirect should be possible while using getStaticProps because of the performance benefits so I will leave this question open.